# hack attempts from IP 127.0.0.1 - is there an exploit to be aware of?

Tags: linux, security, tomcat, java-8

I have noticed numerous entries in Tomcat's local_access_log for various resources coming from IP address 127.0.0.1. These are clearly attempts to hack in. For example, here is a request to get access to the "manager" app:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2015:13:35:13 +0000] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2474
```

here is another one:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2015:21:23:37 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
```

When decoded, the URL is this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2015:21:23:37  0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env="yes" -d cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
```

There are lots of such entries, all from IP address 127.0.0.1. Obviously, since this is the address of localhost, I can't block it. More over, I am not sure if there is something that I can do about it. Is there possibly an exploit that should be patched up? For instance, is there a version of Tomcat that has a related vulnerability? I am running Tomcat 8.

Much thanks for any advice!

UPDATE: thanks for the suggestion about a proxy. Turned out that httpd was indeed installed and not surprisingly, there are suspicious request. For example:

```
[Sat Mar 30 17:26:49 2013] [error] [client 5.34.247.59] Invalid URI in request GET /_mem_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0
[Sat Mar 30 17:26:49 2013] [error] [client 5.34.247.59] Invalid URI in request GET /_mem_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sat Mar 30 17:26:49 2013] [error] [client 5.34.247.59] Invalid URI in request GET /_mem_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
```

This is not a windows system so cmd.exe has not place for it...

Comment: Are you using any proxy on the same computer?

Comment: Is your Tomcat instance directly accessible over the Internet or is there a proxy server like Apache in front of it (possibly running on the same machine as the Tomcat instance)?  If yes, that could be the reason why you are seeing `127.0.0.1` as the IP address.  Examine the proxy logs for the same time period to find out the real IP address.  You can then block those IP addresses on the firewall.

Comment: There is no proxy that I am aware of. I specifically checked for Apache and it is NOT installed. I also checked for environment variables, such as "http_proxy" but none are set.

Comment: UPDATE: turned out that apache was installed, it's just that it was installed as "httpd". This is an Amazon EC2 instance and apparently httpd is used as a mechanism for making server updates vi the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy server running on your computer, that will often receive requests and then call the primary server using the localhost (127.0.0.1) interface.

This could explain why you're logging these requests.